# What is the difference between syntax error and semantics error and logical error?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between syntax error and semantics error and logical error?
in javaScript
I want examples !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax errors are a computer not being able to posses an imput.

Like this:

`answer = 1 +/ 6`

The computer does not recognize the `+/`



a semantics error are human errors.  The computer will execute the code, but it will not be as wanted

Like this:

```
if(player = win){
     print "You Lose"
}
```

It will print "You Lose" if they player won.



A logical error is a synonym for semantics error.

Comment: Thanks , I get it now :)

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error is an error which will make your code "unprocessable".

```
if true {}
```

instead of

```
if (true) {}
```

for example

Semantics error and logical errors are the same. Your code is correct, but doesn't do what you think it does.

```
while(c = true) {}
```

instead of

```
while (c == true) {}
```

for example